# Content Elements and P&T Fieldpack List Problem

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack, content-elements

Trying to use the P&T List from the Fieldpack within Content Elements and the values do not seem to parse. Example code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="page" ...}

  {!-- Content Elements Field --}
  {cf_page_body}

    {textarea}
      <p>{value}</p>
    {/textarea}

    {fieldpack_list}
      <ul class="compact-list">
        {values}
          <li>{item}</li>
        {/values}
      </ul>
    {/fieldpack_list}

  {/cf_page_body}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The output does not seem to get parsed only for fieldpack's list element in CE, neither the "values" tag pair or the "item" var - i.e.; it's returned as:

```
{values}
  <li>{item}</li>
{/values}
```

Any ideas? I've tried numerous variations on the fieldpack's list [Content Elements tag syntax](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/fieldtypes/list/element_tags.html) in case it is a documentation error, tried running the values through Stash as a stash list with parse depth set accordingly, setting parse="inward" on the EE channel tag, but to no avail.

**Project Setup Info:**

- ExpressionEngine Ver. 2.7.3
- Content Elements Ver. 1.6.10
- P&T Fieldpack Ver. 2.1.1
- Stash Ver. 2.5.3

Answer (score 1):

In case any others might be struggling with this annoying problem: it's a compatibility issue, get the latest Field Pack (2.2) and everything works as it should :)

The Field Pack Changelog lists the following updates for Content Elements support:

- Added support for {element_name} tags within Content Elements.
- Fixed compatibility issues iwth Content Elements.

http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/changelog.html

Comment: also don't worry about data loss when you activate field pack P&T will be deactivated automatically. and your data is 100% secured during this process.